# django Models getting user info

Tags: python, django, django-models

trying to create a model that has an artist and song and lets you know what user name typed it in.
so far I have in my models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Song(models.Model):

uesrname = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
artist = models.CharField(max_length=30)
song=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I added a form that works with user input data but the form lets me select one of all exciting Users and input artist, song

```
forms.py
class NewSong(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Song
        exclude = ['username']
```

how can I change it so I will have only my own loged in user in the form?

Comment: The error is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude username field as `exclude = ['username']` on your *forms.py* file and set username to `request.user` on form's save method. For more information: [selecting fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use)

Comment: it dose hide the username part but this code isnt working             if form.is_valid():
            instance=form.save(commit=False)
            instance.username=request.user
            instance.save()

Comment: What is the error? Can you also share your forms.py file in your question?

Comment: the error is that it must be a User instance and User.objects.get(request.user) not working as well

Comment: If a user logged in and hit form's save button, request.user should return a User object. Did you check that before showing the form? You can also use request.user.is_authanticated() method to make sure before setting to instance.